# How do I pause and resume audio when clicking again on the same ListView?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have a ListView activity showing a list of songs from my raw file, when I click on one of the ListView it will play the song accordingly but if I click for the second time it would just replay the same song again. How do I pause and resume again on the same track? Below are the codes I have done so far.

`MainActivity.java`

```
package com.example.myapplication;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private ListView musicListView;
private Trackmodel[] tracklist;
private TrackAdapter adapter;
private MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    musicListView = findViewById(R.id.musicListView);
    loadTracks();

    musicListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            loadTracks();
            Trackmodel track = tracklist[i];

            if (mediaPlayer != null) {
                if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
                    mediaPlayer.stop();
                    mediaPlayer.reset();
                    track.setPlaying(false);
                }
            }

            try {
                mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, track.getId());
                if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
                    mediaPlayer.stop();
                    mediaPlayer.reset();
                    track.setPlaying(false);
                } else {
                    mediaPlayer.start();
                    track.setPlaying(true);
                }

            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("Exception", e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    });
}

public void loadTracks() {
    tracklist = new Trackmodel[]{
            new Trackmodel(R.raw.decode, "Paramore - Decode", false),
            new Trackmodel(R.raw.thats_what_you_get, "Paramore - That's What You Get", false),
            new Trackmodel(R.raw.starstrukk, "30H!3 - Starstrukk", false),
            new Trackmodel(R.raw.we_are_young, "30H!3 - We Are Young", false)
    };
    adapter = new TrackAdapter(MainActivity.this, tracklist);
    musicListView.setAdapter(adapter);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();

    if (mediaPlayer != null) {
        if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
            mediaPlayer.stop();
            mediaPlayer.reset();
        }
    }
}}
```

`TrackModel.java`

```
package com.example.myapplication;

public class Trackmodel {
private int id;
private String name;
private boolean isPlaying;

public Trackmodel(int id, String name, boolean isPlaying) {
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
    this.isPlaying = isPlaying;
}

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public boolean isPlaying() {
    return isPlaying;
}

public void setPlaying(boolean playing) { isPlaying = playing; }
}
```

`TrackAdapter.java`

```
package com.example.myapplication;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.ContentInfo;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class TrackAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

private Context context;
private Trackmodel[] tracks;

TrackAdapter(Context context, Trackmodel[] tracks) {
    this.context = context;
    this.tracks = tracks;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return tracks.length;
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int i) {
    return tracks[i];
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int i) {
    return i;
}

@Override
public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
    Trackmodel track = (Trackmodel) getItem(i);
    ViewHolder holder;

    if (view == null) {
        view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.track_item, viewGroup, false);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.trackImage = view.findViewById(R.id.track_image);
        holder.titleText = view.findViewById(R.id.track_title);
        view.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
    }
    holder.titleText.setText(track.getName());

    if (track.isPlaying()) {
        holder.trackImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_baseline_pause_circle);
    } else {
        holder.trackImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_baseline_play_circle);
    }
    return view;
}

static class ViewHolder {
    ImageView trackImage;
    TextView titleText;
}
}
```

`track_item.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/sound_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:paddingLeft="16sp"
android:paddingTop="10dp"
android:paddingRight="16sp">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/track_image"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:padding="5dp"
    app:tint="@android:color/black" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/track_title"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="56dp"
    android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body2" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

`activity_main.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/musicListView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your item click, you stop the `MediaPlayer` but after that, you create a new instance every time.
You have one if check, which checks if `MediaPlayer` is playing and stops it. After that, you create a `new MediaPlayer` and perform the same check again. So what is happening when you click the first time? First `if` check is not executing because your `mediaplayer` is null, it creates a new `mediaplayer` and starts to play.
After clicking the second time your first `if` check is executing, because your MediaPlayer is not null and `isPlaying` is true. You stop it, create a new instance of `MediaPlayer` and play it again. That's why after clicking all the next times you just replay the song. Because on click you stop the song, create a new instance and play it.

So what you need here, I assume you have different tracks in your list and when you click on another track you need to stop the previous track and start that new one. But if you click on the same track you want to pause it.

In this case, you need the current track id which is playing/played. After clicking next time if the track id is the same which was playing, you just pause it. If it's another track, stop it and start that new track. Here's the below code, you can make changes accordingly and apply it to your code.

```
int currentTrackId = -1;
    musicListView.setOnItemClickListener(
            (AdapterView.OnItemClickListener) (adapterView, view, i, l) -> {
        loadTracks();
        Trackmodel track = tracklist[i];
        if (currentTrackId != -1 && track.getId() == currentTrackId) {
            // That was the same song, just pause it.
            if (mediaPlayer != null) {
                if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
                    mediaPlayer.pause();
                    track.setPlaying(false);
                } else {
                    mediaPlayer.start();
                    track.setPlaying(true);
                }
            }
        } else {
            // That's another song, stop the previous one and start the new one
            currentTrackId = track.getId();
            if (mediaPlayer != null) {
                mediaPlayer.stop();
                mediaPlayer.reset();
            }

            try {
                mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, track.getId());
                mediaPlayer.start();
                track.setPlaying(true);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("Exception", e.getMessage());
            }  
        }
    });
```

Comment: I have tried that before, somehow it didn't work and still replay the same.

Comment: I guess I understand your problem now.

Comment: I'll update my answer shortly.

Comment: The pause works but when starting a new track, it doesn't stop the previous track so there are multiple tracks playing.

Comment: I have added another `if (mediaPlayer != null)` and it works! Thank you so much for your time I really appreciate it.

Comment: Glad it worked. Where did you put that if check, so I could edit my answer?

Comment: Just before `currentTrackid = track.getId();` for `mediaplayer.stop()` and `mediaPlayer.reset();`

Comment: Ok I will edit now) Let me know if something will be wrong.

Comment: It's all good now